# How to add Distinct function to a array or return only unique values

Tags: php, pdf, foreach, datatables

How to add distinct function so that the result is not repetitive?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
$yearnow=$_POST['yearnow'];
$stmts = $db->query("select * from tblgencol where year='$yearnow'");
        while($row= $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $pdf->Row(Array($row->busname,$row->business));
            }
        }
```

Here is the output of my code:

[image: Here is the output of my code]

I'm using fpdf to display my data from database. And its working fine. Its just that the name is repeating.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: Here is the sample output i want to do]

or what if i want to display this?

[option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6i4L.png)

Comment: I think a group by will do the trick for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your desired result, you need to check if the current business name is the same as the last displayed one, and if so, not output it:

```
$yearnow=$_POST['yearnow'];
$stmts = $db->query("select * from tblgencol where year='$yearnow'");
$busname = '';
while ($row = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $thisbusname = ($row->busname != $busname) ? $row->busname : '';
    $pdf->Row(array($thisbusname,$row->business));
    $busname = $row->busname;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate this works perfectly. I have one more favor what if its like the option 2 above. How can i do that?

Comment: @Lucky to do option 2, change the query to `"select busname, group_concat(business) as business from tblgencol where year='$yearnow' group by busname"` and go back to your original loop code.

Comment: i have a lil bit of problem mate. Like on the 1st option above. The business owner is printing on the 2nd row (Juan, Laundry )while the business is printed on the first row. How can i fix that?

Comment: @Lucky sorry mate I had a typo. See the edit to this line: `$thisbusname = ($row->busname != $busname) ? $row->busname : '';`